# How should I name fields in a relational database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm about to create a database that has fields that will appear in a few different tables (as keys).  For example, in my listing table I will have MLS_ID.  This field will also appear in the listing_photos table.  Should I prefix the field name to make it unique:  listings_MLS_ID as an example?

Comment: I would suggest giving the column the same name in every table within which it appears (it makes join conditions easier - one can use `USING` or even `NATURAL JOIN` to amalgamate the common columns).

Comment: There are varied opinions on this:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114728/why-is-naming-a-tables-primary-key-column-id-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is absolutely no point in doing that. you could ALWAYS prefix your fieldname with both database and table names, getting your unique identifier, keeping the name itself neat and concise.

```
listings.mls.id
```

will address an `id` field in the `mls` table which belongs to `listings` database.

this is going to be quite flexible: any time you need long unique identifier - you have it.
in all other cases you can use short name.

Answer (score 1):

Name the key the same in both tables (MLS_ID). The database server rewards you for doing this by letting you use the more concise `USING` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM listings
JOIN listing_photos
  USING (MLS_ID)
```

Rather than this:

```
SELECT * FROM listings
JOIN listing_photos
  ON listing_photos.listings_MLS_ID = listings.MLS_ID
```

Comment: Not that big of a reward really, especially in an ORM day and age.

Answer (score 0):

this is personal preference.

for me:

i do not prefix with the local table name except on the primary key. e.g.
PERSON table will get a PERSON_ID column, ADDRESS table will get ADDRESS_ID etc.

the PERSON_ADDRESS table gets PERSON_ID and ADDRESS_ID, not something else.

in your queries, the column names are equal when they should be equivalent as keys, and the table alias tells you which is which.